# How to round a float value to double value?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, rounding, rounding-error

The follow code round incorrectly for a human people:

```
double d = 0.7F;
System.out.println( d );
```

print the value: 0.699999988079071

The follow code work better:

```
double d = Double.valueOf( Float.toString( 0.7F ));
System.out.println( d );
```

But create an additional String. Are there a more performance conversion of float to double without an extra string?

The code line are simple and demonstrate only the problem. The program is more complex. The float values are in a one part of a complex model. The formatting layer use only double. Also DecimalFormat accept only double and not float.

Comment: If the result is expressed appropriately for humans seems, to me, only to be relevant when the value is presented to humans through `println()`. At that point, it is straightforward to apply a format that represents the level of precision that is required in the output. Is there a particular reason in this case why you want to convert from `float` to `double` in a special way?

Comment: The values are represented in a Swing GUI and formatted with a DecimalFormat which accept only double. There are also other sources with a double precision. There are a large count of API calls between value in the model and the representation in the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what precision you want you can round it to say 6 decimal places. eg.

```
public static double round6(double x) {
    return Math.round(x * 1e6) / 1e6;
}

round6(0.7f) == 0.7
```

The fact the `x` passed in was a `float` doesn't matter provided this precision is suitable.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use

```
double d = 0.7D;
```

Using `F` means it's a `float` constant, and then it's promoted to `double` and may not be the closest number to 0.7 that can be represented with a double precision floating point, as the mantissa is not extended in any way.

`0.7D` is a `double` constant to begin with.

Comment: The code demonstrate only the problem. The values are saved in a model.

Comment: It depends on how you look at it. Of course, no bits are erased. But the mantissa is not extended. So it is not the closest number to `0.7` that can be represented with a double-precision floating point. You lose precision relative to what you could get if you parsed it directly.

Comment: @Horcrux7 then you should consider carefully why you want to work part of the time with single precision, and part of the time with double precision. If precision is important to you, you should save the data in double precision from the start. If you really want to keep `float` data and use `double` manipulation on it, then indeed, all you can do is format it properly at the end.

Answer (score 2):

if it's all about the output (for humans) i would suggest to use printf:

```
System.out.printf("Value: %.2f", d);
```

doing the conversion with FloatingDecimal is surely faster, and prints 0.7 as well

```
  Double doubleResult = new FloatingDecimal(0.7F).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Between the float value and the println (a DecimalFormat.format(double)) are approx 20 API call with double precision.

Comment: maybe FloatingDecimal is of use here, although its sun.misc

Answer (score 2):

> But create an additional String. Are there a more performance conversion of float to double without an extra string?

Allocating a short-lived block of a few bytes is only the tip of the iceberg. The “conversion” that you desire fundamentally requires going from binary floating-point to decimal representation and then back to binary floating-point, and these conversions aren't cheap regardless of how the intermediate decimal representation is stored.

If you know that the `float` values you are concerned with come from decimal values with two digits after the dot, you could use:

```
double d = Math.round(f * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

This incurs only one division plus `Math.round` which is cheaper than one conversion to or from decimal. And any decent compiler should produce code for it that does not allocate.

Answer (score 2):

```
double d = 0.7F;
System.out.println( d );
```

> print the value: 0.699999988079071

The conversion is *correct.*

When you print out a `float f`, it prints out enough digits so that the value it prints out is closer to the *true value of `f`* than any other `float`.

When you print out a `double`, it prints out enough digits so that the value it prints out is closer to the true value of `d` then any other `double`.

The conversion from float to double is exact, it's just showing you a value closer to the true value you'd had in your `float`.  `Double.valueOf( Float.toString( 0.7F ))` is not more accurate; it just pretends your values are nicer than they actually are.

Comment: Say that the `float` type was chosen to represent a decimal number with few significant digits in a piece of code that you didn't write and cannot change. Now assume that the `double` type was chosen to represent a number that's going to be displayed in decimal with as many decimals as necessary to distinguish the `double`, again in a piece of code that you didn't write and cannot change. I believe that this is the situation the OP is in.